# Push notification to all users in firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send a push notification to all users in my firebase app.
is there a way to do it without using a topic?

I have tried doing the following request:

```
{
  "to":"/topics/all", 
   "data":{
      "message" :" {My message}"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Topic will be best suited for this. Is there a reason why you are against using topics?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely can't use a topic, then you will need to collect all the device ID tokens from all your users' app installations, then send the message directly to all those tokens.  But I suspect it will be easier to user a topic instead of writing all that code.